# How to get application class name programmatically

Tags: java, android

I need to get the application's subclass name at run-time for an android application;

e.g. : `public class TargetApplicationClass extends Application{...}`

I would need to get the string value of `TargetApplicationClass`,

is there any way I can do that?

Let me give a bit more details about my case:
I am not working on a simple android application that I already have the context of TargetApplicationClass; I am working on a injection library that has 0 knowledge about the application class; I can enumerate and get some info by

```
app = ActivityThread.currentApplication();
context = app.getApplicationContext();
...
```

The problem is the following code does not necessary return the correct application class name:

```
app.getClass().getName()
```

Comment: `TargetApplicationClass.getClass().getName()`

Comment: If you only want to use the class name, you have to use `getSimpleName()`.

Comment: `yourActivity.getApplication().getClass()`

Answer (score 0):

```
TargetApplicationClass.getClass().getName() // use anyone as per your usecase
//TargetApplicationClass.getClass().getCanonicalName()
//TargetApplicationClass.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that name for Tagging then you can use

```
private String TAG = TargetApplicationClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

But if you want to get the name that you'd use to dynamically load the class with
then you can use

```
private String Name = TargetApplicationClass.class.getName();
```

For more info see this Example

```
System.out.println(String.class.getName());
System.out.println(String.class.getCanonicalName());
System.out.println(String.class.getSimpleName());
```

Output

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
String
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure a quick google search would have sufficed. However, you do `this.getClass().getName()` and make sure it's not running within a static context